# Getting a positional error with python mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

I am getting hundreds of positional errors with  Python mysql connector while trying to populate a database.  I figure it's because I'm not being able to escape some or all of the special characters. Is there a way to escape all the special characters that are causing this problem or; ...should I just go ahead and replace the special characters in each string with other neutral characters and create a dictionary to restructure the sentence back to original when I pull data back from the database?

```
for thing in every_thing:
    line_= thing.split("|", 3)
    book_name = line_[0]
    chap_number = line_[1]
    verse_num = line_[2]
    verse= line_[3]
#Test
    statement = "INSERT INTO " + new_dict[line_[0]]
    statement += " ( " 
    chapters = book_key_chapt[line_[0]]
    h = 1
    fields = ""
    while h <= chapters:
        fields += "Chapter_" + str(h)
        h += 1
        if h != chapters + 1:
            fields += ","
        else:
            fields += " )"
    statement += fields
# Value creation
    values = " VALUES ( "
    a = 1
    while a <= chapters:
        if a == int(chap_number):
            values += "'" + verse_num +  verse.replace('~'," ") + "'"
        else:
            values += "'NA'"
        a += 1
        if a != chapters + 1:
            values += "," 
    values += " )"
    statement += values
    try:
        cur.execute(*statement)
        print(cur)
    except Exception as er:
        print(er)
```

Comment: This is the error  sql statement  'execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 844 were given'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
cur.execute(*statement)
```

The "*" means ["unpack before passing"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). It's usually applied to lists or tuples but works on any iterable - and strings *are* iterable. So basically, what your doing here is:

```
cur.execute(statemement[0], statement[1], statement[2], # etc)
```

So we know your `statement` string is 844 characters long ;-)

The solution is, of course, to remove the "*".

**This being said**, your code is [totally unsafe](https://bobby-tables.com/), and even if no one uses this breach to attack you, it's still very brittle (properly escaping strings is not that simple). The proper way to use the db-api is to [use placeholders in the SQL query and pass the values as arguments](https://bobby-tables.com/python)

Note that this only applies to *values*, not to tables and fields names, so you still have to programmatically build the SQL query, but you can make your life much easier (and your code a bit faster) by using string formatting operations, and by building your fields list and placeholders list using `str.join(seq)`, ie:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO {table_name} ({fields}) VALUES ({placeholders})"

# NB: you may want to read about the stdlib's `csv` package...
book_name, chap_number, verse_num, verse = thing.split("|", 3)

table_name = new_dict[book_name]
nb_chapters = book_key_chapt[book_name]

fields = ["Chapter_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, nb_chapters + 1)]
placeholders = ["?"] * nb_chapters

values = [#XXX I let you rewrite your code here using a list comprehension as above]

sql = statement.format(
    table_name=table_name, 
    fields=", ".join(fields), 
    placeholders=", ".join(placeholders)
    )

cur.execute(sql, values)
```

**And as a last (but important!) note**: it looks like you're having one distinct table per book name, each with as many fields as chapters ? If yes, **that's a totally wrong design**. If the point is to model a book + chapters you want one single table for the books (one record per book), and a related "chapters" table with a foreignkey on the "books" table (one record per chapter).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely have to follow your solution because I have 66 tables (one for each book) and I even know that's too many.  However, I'm glad to be learning and people like you make it much better and easier. Thank you boss!

Comment: The reason why i was unpacking the statement was because it allowed me to get through a connection problem i was having with mysql. I'll rewrite everything though. better safe than sorry.

Comment: " I have 66 tables (one for each book) and I even know that's too many" => it's not a matter of how many tables you have, it's a matter of structuring your data so that you can use them. How are you going to display a listing of your books if they are in different tables ? How are you going to write an UI that allow your app users to add new books ? How are you going to select authors having published more than 3 books in the past 5 years ? What about books with different editions ? You have to think in terms of entities (book, chapter, author, editors) and relationships between those entities